# What's wrong with my htaccess ? (500 Error)

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, http-code-500, browser-detecting

I've written a small htaccess file to redirect Internet Explorer users to a specific page
Here are the contents :

```
# MS Internet Explorer - Mozilla v4
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/4(.*)MSIE
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /sorry.php [L]

# All other browsers
#RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.32.html [L]
```

Any clue why this would give a 500 Internal Server Error ?
I have used mod rewrite before so i have the module loaded there...

Comment: Are there any hints in Apache's error logs?

Comment: i checked on the server in my `logs` folder, tho there are no files there i have no clue why (im hosted with Godaddy) and i have access via SSH if that helps..

Comment: do both sorry.php and index.32.html exist? Are they in the right directory? Is this for a base level page or for a page somewhere deep inside a directory structure?

Comment: only sorry.php exist (the line for index.32) is commented out....
and this is at the root, nothing else there (for now)

Comment: replace sorry.php with a normal .html page and see if it still throws an error. PHP is known to cause "500" errors when it has terminal errors.

Comment: thanks for the continuous support, first what do you mean by terminal errors ? and second, sadly, it still wont go, im starting to wonder if this is currently a godaddy issue tho im still waiting for a reply from them :(

Comment: If you have access to server config put it to your server config `RewriteLogLevel 5RewriteLog "path/to/logs/RewriteLog.log"`, test the page and **REMOVE** it and put rewrite log here!

Comment: i don't have access to httpd config, tho i have ssh access and php.ini but im sure php has nothing to do with it
will this work in a regular htaccess file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a good reply from support
Looks like, for some reason, i need to have `RewriteBase /` in every .htaccess that uses mod rewrite in order for that module to work correctly, idk why but that seems to fix the problem
Thanks for all the great comments tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

Then tell me as a comment what it gives and I'll update my answer to help you.

Comment: i've been also fighting with logs, can't seem to get some lately, especially from php's, but i'll give your code a shot tomorrow and let you know :)

Comment: i finally got a good reply from support and fixed the problem, tho i didn't need this, i'll keep it in mind for future debug +1

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, I changed ^Mozilla/4(.*)MSIE to !^Mozilla/4(.*)MSIE to test it with any other browser. Normally a HTTP 500 error when modifing your htaccess means that something is incorrect with the htaccess file. Copied from apache manual at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Mozilla/4.*
RewriteRule ^foo\.html$         foo.NS.html          [L]
```

Some apache versions or installations do not like redirects without a full url: (one server I work on)

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/sorry.php [L]
```

Different browser selections could be written like below:

```
# Mozilla 4/5 Browsers 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[4-5]\.[0-9]+\ \(compatible;\ MSIE\ [3-9]\.[0-9.]+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[4-5]\.[0-9]+\ \(Macintosh;\ .+\)\ \AppleWebKit/[1-9]\.[0-9.]+\ \(KHTML,\ like\ Gecko\)\ \Safari/[0-9]{3,8}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[4-5]\.[0-9]+\ \(Macintosh;\ I;\ PPC\)$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[4-5]\.[0-9]+\ \(X11;\ U;\ Linux\ i686;\ [a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2};\ rv:[1-9]\.[0-9.]+\)\ Gecko/Debian-[1-9]\.[0-9.]+-[0-9]+\ Galeon/[2-9]\.[0-9.]+\ \(Debian\ package\ [2-9]\.[0-9.]+-[0-9]+\)$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[4-5]\.[0-9]+\ \(compatible;\ Konqueror/([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+.+\ 20[0-9]{6}\)$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[4-5]\.[0-9]+\ \(compatible;\ Konqueror/([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+;\ Linux\)\ \(KHTML,\ like\ Gecko\)$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[4-5]\.[0-9]+\ \(.+;\ rv:([0-9]+\.)+[0-9a-z]+\)\ Gecko/20[0-9]{6} 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[4-5]\.[0-9]+\ WebTV/([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+\ \(compatible;\ MSIE\ [5-9]\.[0-9]+ 
# Others 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Avant\ Browser\ \(http://www\.avantbrowser\.com\)$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Microsoft\ Internet\ Explorer/[34]\.[0-9]{1,2} 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/(3\.01¦4\.0)\ \(compatible;\)$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/[3-4]\.[0-9]+\ \[[a-z]{2}\](\ \(.+\))? 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/4\.0\ \(PSP\ \(PlayStation\ Portable\);\ [0-9.]+\)$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Opera/[5-9]\.[0-9]+
```

Comment: lol thats a bit overkill for what i am trying to do tho i'll leave it for later thanks :)